# textChanged event doesn´t fire and i have autopostback=true

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a textbox event declarated but it doesn´t fire. I have seen in SO other answers but all of them say that autopostback property has been true and i have it

my aspx

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" />    
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDia" Width="120px" Height="20px" 
                AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="textbox" OnTextChanged="txtDia_TextChanged"/>
            <Juice:Datepicker ID="Datepicker2" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtDia" 
                DateFormat="dd/mm/yy" 
                MonthNames="Enero,Febrero,Marzo,Abril,Mayo,Junio,Julio,Agosto,Septiembre,Octubre,Noviembre,Diciembre" 
                MonthNamesShort="Ene,Feb,Mar,Abr,May,Jun,Jul,Ago,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dic," 
                AutoPostBack="True" /></td>
```

and my aspx.vb

```
Protected Sub txtDia_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles         txtDia.TextChanged
        CargarDatos()
End Sub
```

Comment: ok i think the problem is with my datepicker control, becouse with normal textbox it works well. Sorry for your time

Comment: Is it under `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: no, i have edited the question

Answer (score 3):

You should define your textbox like this (see `OnTextChanged="txtDia_TextChanged"` being added):

```
<asp:TextBox OnTextChanged="txtDia_TextChanged" 
              runat="server" ID="txtDia" Width="120px" Height="20px" 
              AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="textbox"/>
```

And remember that this event will rise onblur (focus removed from that textbox) only.

Comment: That is not necessary in VB.NET with the `Handles` keyword.

Comment: I do it with designer. now i write OnTextChanged="txtDia_TextChanged" too but it doesn´t work

Comment: @Mikelon85 How do you know it is not working? What should happen and what happens instead? Just to be clear: postback will not rise while you are typing. You must remove focus from that field in order to rise postback event.

Comment: i fill textbox with a datepicker. and then i push tab, return everythingh. It should happend cargarDatos(). I do the same with a dropdownlist onSelectedIndexChanged event and it works perfect

Comment: Oh. Datepicker. That may happen because you are opening datapicker in that field and then select some date there. Focus is lost BEFORE value is changed and postback will not rise (no text changes).

Comment: Try to edit date value without using datepicker (even if it will open, you should be able to edit date manually). In that case it should rise postback. If so, then you will need to fire blur event on your textbox after date is selected.

Answer (score 2):

In your aspx you should write

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDia" Width="120px" Height="20px" 
                AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="textbox" OnTextChanged="txtDia_TextChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The event is not triggered if you overwrite the text in codebehind. So for example if you databind the control where the `TextBox` sits in.

You should so that only `If Not IsPostBack`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostback)
    {
        DataBindAllControls(); // including your textbox
    }
}
```

Edit: Sorry, here VB.NET:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        DataBindAllControls() ' including your textbox
    Else
End Sub
```

Comment: i use txtdia.databind() in order DataBindAllControls becouse it doesn´t exists

Answer (score 1):

What FAngel said is correct.

I've had the same issue when validating dates and using jquery datepicker. I used the below to fire the validation routines after the box had been populated. So technically they fired twice, once after the textbox had lost focus to the datepicker, then again when my code fired after the datepicker had populated the textbox. It would have been better to disable the onblur event and call directly from the below, but wasn't possible in my project.

```
$('.datePicker').each(function () {
     $(this).datepicker({
          onSelect: function () {
                $(this).trigger('blur');
          }
     });
});
```

You can use a variation on this by disabling the auto-postback and manually triggering it via the onSelect event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the method to be called when the event is fired like so:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtDia" Width="120px" Height="20px" OnTextChanged="txtDia_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="textbox"/>
```

Note:

```
OnTextChanged="txtDia_TextChanged"
```